# How to handle restAPI and redux with Lit-Element?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, redux, lit-element

I'm using Javascript, Lit-Element, Express, Mongoose and Redux.

I don't know why, but when I click on a link that do a GET request the page-view is not re-rendered correctly. Probably it's a problem with redux because I didn't have this problem before I modified my app with redux.

For example, if I click on this button, the url on the address bar is changed from 'localhost/items' to 'localhost/items?color=red', but OFTEN the page-view is the same as before: I don't see my filtered list of 'items', but all the items. SOMETIMES the filter button works.

```
<a href='/items?color=red'><button @click="${()=>updateList('color=red')}">Show red items</button></a>
```

updateList(filter) function:

```
updateList(filter){
    store.dispatch(fetchItemsList(filter));
}
```

Redux action:

```
export const fetchItemsList = (searchParams) => (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`/api/items?${searchParams}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => dispatch(updateItems(res)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
  
  const updateItems = (list) => {
    return {
      type: UPDATE_ITEMS_LIST,
      list: list
    };
  };
```

Reducer:

```
const START_STATE = {
    list: []
};

const features = (state = START_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_ITEMS_LIST:
            return action.list.reduce((o, item) => ({...o, [item._id]: item}), {});
        default:
            return state;
    }
 };
```

Basically I have a table with a list of items with different features, one of these is the item color. I want to use rest api to filter my items list.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of fire-and-forget promises here - they go do something, but nothing comes back to the LitElement to tell it that it has an update to render.

You need something to go back to the `LitElement` and either set an observed property or call `requestUpdate()`.

A good way to do this with Redux would be a [`ReactiveController`](https://lit.dev/docs/composition/controllers/) that manages your Redux actions and calls `this.host.requestUpdate()` when there are changes to re-render.